# Find which TTY port Arduino is connected to in Ubuntu using C/C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, serial-port, arduino

I'm writing a program in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++), and it is required to communicate to an Arduino via [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus). Each time the Arduino restarts, it is possible that the port the Arduino is connected to changes (for example, located at `/dev/ttyAMC0`, Arduino restart, connected at `/dev/ttyAMC1`).

The code I am using is

```
#include <fcntl.h>
...
arduino = open("/dev/ttyAMC0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if(arduino != -1) 
    fcntl(_arduino, F_SETFL, 0);
...
```

Each time the Arduino changes port locations, I have to manually change this in my code and then re-compile my program.

Is there a way to determine exactly which port the Arduino connected to, and have the location returned to me as a string (that is, "/dev/ttyACM1")?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364879/linux-and-python-auto-detect-arduino-serial-port

Comment: That post is focused on using Python, not c/c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- Try to open `/dev/ttyACM0`
- If that fails try to open `/dev/ttyACM0`

Something like this:

```
#define SERIALIDX_MIN   0
#define SERIALIDX_MAX   1

int idxSerialPortIndex = SERIALIDX_MIN;
char strSerialPort[oxFF];

while (true) {
   sprintf(strSerialPort, "/dev/ttyAMC%d", idxSerialPortIndex);
   arduino = open("/dev/ttyAMC0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
   if(arduino != -1) {
       fcntl(_arduino, F_SETFL, 0);
       ...  // read serial port here
   }
   if (++idxSerialPortIndex > SERIALIDX_MAX) 
       idxSerialPortIndex = SERIALIDX_MIN;
}
```

If you are worried that other devices will show up on `/dev/ttyACM0` and `/dev/ttyACM1` you can make your Arduino respond to simple command string. If it reads `ID` followed by LF (or CR/LF depending on your system), it can respond with some suitable string like `**I AM THE MOTHERBUSTING ARDUINO**`, whereupon your C/C++ program will know if it is indeed connected to an Arduino. If the expected response isn't received, the C/C++ program can open the next serial port.